# Develop GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

It needs to display my picture on the left and my first and last name along with birthdate on the right side. This is what I have so far, but it keeps giving me a TCL error saying "No such file or directory" when I have the file saved onto my computer.

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label,PhotoImage,LEFT,RIGHT

root=Tk()

text=Label(root,
       text="First Name: Justin\n"

            "Last Name: Joseph\n"

            "Date of Birth:02/17/1995")

text.pack(side=RIGHT)

Justin=PhotoImage(file="Justin.gif")
JustinLabel=Label(root,
              image=Justin)
JustinLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: maybe you haven't provided the path name correctly.

Comment: If it's telling you "no such file or directory", you can believe it. Perhaps it's not looking in the directory you think it is. Names are relative to your working directory, _not_ the directory where the script is (unless, of course, the script is in the current directory)

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the line:

```
Justin=PhotoImage(file="Justin.gif")
```

Make sure that Justin.gif is located in the right place in the file hierarchy (same directory as the script itself) and is called 'Justin.gif' (capitalization sensitive).

Comment: It needs to be in same working directory, not location.